# Verification of signature without signed attributes using Bouncy Castle 1.70

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, signature, verification

I've started working on this project where we use Bouncy Castle for verification of digital signatures and we stumbled upon a bug.
This is verification method:
`

```
private Set<TLName> verifySignature(PDSignature sig, X509Certificate signerCertificate, SignerInformation signerInfo, List<X509Certificate> chain, SignatureInfo signatureInfo) throws OperatorCreationException {
        Set<TLName> emptyTrustedBy = new HashSet<>(TLName.values().length);

        // checking cert validity at signing time
        try {
            signerCertificate.checkValidity(sig.getSignDate().getTime());
        } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) {
            LOG.info("Signature verification failed, certificate is expired.");
            return emptyTrustedBy;
        } catch (CertificateNotYetValidException e) {
            LOG.info("Signature verification failed, certificate is not yet valid.");
            return emptyTrustedBy;
        }

        // check all certificates from chain on trust lists
        Set<TLName> filledTrustedBy = TrustedCertificates.getTrustedByForChain(chain.toArray(new X509Certificate[0]));
        if (filledTrustedBy.isEmpty()) {
            LOG.info("Signature verification failed, certificate not found between our trusted certificates.");
            return emptyTrustedBy;
        }

        // verifying signature with public key
        SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(signerCertificate);
        try {
            if (signerInfo.verify(verifier)) {
                signatureInfo.signedBytesUnchanged = true;
                signatureInfo.checksum = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signerInfo.getContentDigest());
                LOG.debug("Signature verification completed, signature verified.");
                return filledTrustedBy; // only here return trustedBy array filled with values
            }
            signatureInfo.checksum = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signerInfo.getContentDigest());
        } catch (CMSException e) {
            LOG.info("Signature verification failed, couldn't verify signature. Exception message: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return emptyTrustedBy;
    }
```

From what I researched about usage of this library the statement `if (signerInfo.verify(verifier)) { ...}` should be a legit way to use it. But we had an additional layer where we calculated checksum ourselves to be checked in different component of our project:

```
 private void checkSignedBytes(SignerInformation signerInfo, File inFile, int[] byteRange, SignatureInfo signatureInfo) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        Attribute attribute = signerInfo.getSignedAttributes().get(CMSAttributes.messageDigest);
        DEROctetString sigDigest = (DEROctetString) attribute.getAttrValues().getObjectAt(0);
        byte[] sigDigestBytes = sigDigest.getOctets();

        byte[] contentDigestBytes = Signer.getDigest(inFile, byteRange, signerInfo.getDigestAlgOID());

        signatureInfo.checksum = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(sigDigestBytes);
        signatureInfo.signedBytesUnchanged = Arrays.equals(sigDigestBytes, contentDigestBytes);
    }
```

This used to work until we stumbled upon a case where we encountered digital signature without signed attributes. I've tried to study the library but because of some problem I am not able to debug it. From what can I tell happens in `doVerify( ... )` method in `SignerInformation` class of Bouncy Castle signatures without signed attributes are handled.

Digest calculation:

```
 if (signedAttributeSet == null)
                    {
                        if (contentVerifier instanceof RawContentVerifier)
                        {
                            content.write(digOut);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            OutputStream cOut = new TeeOutputStream(digOut, sigOut);

                            content.write(cOut);

                            cOut.close();
                        }
                    }
```

Verification:

```
if (signedAttributeSet == null && resultDigest != null)
            {
                if (contentVerifier instanceof RawContentVerifier)
                {
                    RawContentVerifier rawVerifier = (RawContentVerifier)contentVerifier;

                    if (encName.equals("RSA"))
                    {
                        DigestInfo digInfo = new DigestInfo(new AlgorithmIdentifier(digestAlgorithm.getAlgorithm(), DERNull.INSTANCE), resultDigest);

                        return rawVerifier.verify(digInfo.getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER), this.getSignature());
                    }

                    return rawVerifier.verify(resultDigest, this.getSignature());
                }
            }
```

To my question - I have moved logic of the second method `checkSignedBytes( ... )` to the first method `verifySignature( ... )` here:

```
if (signerInfo.verify(verifier)) {
                signatureInfo.signedBytesUnchanged = true;
                signatureInfo.checksum = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(signerInfo.getContentDigest());
                LOG.debug("Signature verification completed, signature verified.");
                return filledTrustedBy; // only here return trustedBy array filled with values
            }
```

Should this be ok? Is there some information lost because of absence of signed attributes? Given that those attributes are needed in different component I have no choice but to initialize them despite how redundant it might seem. Thank you for your answers!

Described in details above.